# Creating a new column using two columns from the data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

Below is an example of the data frame

```
  A    B 
| 0  | NA |
| 1  | NA |
| 1  | 0  |
| 1  | 0  |
| 1  | 1  |
| 0  | NA |
| 1  | NA |
| 1  | 0  |
| 1  | 0  |
| 1  | 1  |
```

Using the values in the A and B columns how can we achieve a new column that follows the following conditions :

```
if A = 0 AND B = NA then put '0' in new col
if A = 1 AND B = 0 then put '0' in new col
if A = 1 and B = 1 then put '1' in new col
if A = 1 and B = NA then put 'NA' in new col
```

An ideal new column would look like the following:

```
  A    B    new_col
| 0  | NA | 0  
| 1  | NA | NA
| 1  | 0  | 0
| 1  | 0  | 0
| 1  | 1  | 1
| 0  | NA | 0  
| 1  | NA | NA
| 1  | 0  | 0
| 1  | 0  | 0
| 1  | 1  | 1
```

I could not find an appropriate solution for this yet. If something is unclear and needs more explanation, please comment. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` is your friend here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, probably you can summarize the logic as below

```
# if `A==0`, output `0`, otherwise, yielding values of `B`
> transform(df, new_col = ifelse(A == 0, 0, B))
   A  B new_col
1  0 NA       0
2  1 NA      NA
3  1  0       0
4  1  0       0
5  1  1       1
6  0 NA       0
7  1 NA      NA
8  1  0       0
9  1  0       0
10 1  1       1
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
    B = c(NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = case_when(
      A == 0 & is.na(B) ~ "0", 
      A == 1 & B == 0 ~ "0", 
      A == 1 & B == 1 ~ "1", 
      TRUE ~ NA)
  )
#    A  B newcol
# 1  0 NA      0
# 2  1 NA   <NA>
# 3  1  0      0
# 4  1  0      0
# 5  1  1      1
# 6  0 NA      0
# 7  1 NA   <NA>
# 8  1  0      0
# 9  1  0      0
# 10 1  1      1
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), B = c(NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `hailnet = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `names(message) <- `*vtmp*``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]


I got this error while compiling the code. The structure of the selected variable columns is integer.

Comment: It works with the data in your question, no idea without something more representative (for what is different)

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. You are right that it works with the sample I provided but does not work with my source data, had this same error while I was trying to solve it with the solutions mentioned in questions similar to mine. Would like to know how to solve it and run it with your provided solution.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution using ThomasIsCoding's answer, `ifelse` (though better `dplyr::if_else`) is a good path. For future questions, if there is any doubt, it can be better to provide something like `dput(x)` instead so that we can see the corner cases better. The determination of `x` and row/column-sampling is an art-form, nothing strict, often `head(dat,20)` can work but if you have grouping or matching-criteria, you might need a few more minutes to make sure the sample you provide is sufficient. I applaud the **simple** sample data, though, I appreciate your effort there. Thanks!